# Detect multiple keyboard press in windows store app/winRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have to perform a task when the user presses UP + RIGHT + A .

each of UP , RIGHT and A all three have different functions of their own. It's just that when pressed together all of them should happen but unfortunately when I try to do it using `KeyDown` then only A is getting executed :-(

Is there anyway to do it with `KeyDown` or any other way using anything else ??

UP ,RIGHT and A are keyBoard Buttons..

This code is not working:-

```
if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Up  ) {
           .... 
}
if(e.key == VirtualKey.Down) {
            .....   
}
if(e.key == VirtualKey.A) {
             ...
}

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course it doesn't work, since `e` is an instance of [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx) and it thus only represents one key. I think, however, that the KeyDown event is called for every key that is pressed, even if simultaneously. So, what you need to do is the following:

1. Create an IEnumerable of Keys, which may be a List for example
2. Create a bool indicating if at least one key is down, which you can control via the KeyX events. If you need help on that please comment.
3. On the KeyDown event, add e.key to that list, and clear it when your value is set to false

You now have a list containing every key that is currently being held, and you can use it to check multiple keypresses.
If you need a code example, I'll add it.